# How to draw parallelograms (diamond grid)?

Tags: java, graphics, line

I have to program a diamond patterned flag that has a width of 160 and a height of 100, like so:

[image]
<sub>(source: [loeser.us](http://www.loeser.us/flags/images/colonial/lordbaltimore.gif))</sub>

However, when I do the program it's not turning out to be parallel and straight. Any suggestions on what I need to do? Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;

import java.applet.*; 

import java.awt.*; 

public class Flag extends Applet 

{ 

    public void paint(Graphics g) 

    { 

        g.setColor(Color.blue); 
        g.fillRect(0,0,160,100);  

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        int x1[] = {0, 0, 53, 53, 26, 26};
        int y1[] = {0, 8, 44, 100, 100, 0}; 
        g.fillPolygon (x1, y1, 6); 

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        int x2[] = {26, 80, 80, 106, 106, 80, 53, 53 }; 
        int y2[] = {0, 32, 100, 100, 80, 60, 44, 0};  
        g.fillPolygon (x2, y2, 8); 

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        int x3[] = {80, 80, 133, 133, 106, 106}; 
        int y3[] = {0, 32, 64, 100, 80, 0}; 
        g.fillPolygon (x3, y3, 6); 

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        int x4[] = {133, 133, 160, 160};
        int y4[] = {0, 64, 80, 0};  
        g.fillPolygon (x4, y4, 4); 

    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "diamonds", do you mean ◆◇? Because if  so, I fail to see why you try to express them with more than four coordinates.

Comment: This is a visual question.  We need you to include an image (or at least a link to an image, so someone else can edit into the question) of what you are currently seeing as a result of your code.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say it should look like this: <http://www.loeser.us/flags/images/colonial/lordbaltimore.gif > . I'm having trouble calculating the correct coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for the intended result; it helps. What does it look like with your current code?

Comment: First, there are six background rectangles which have equal widths. How are you supposed to do that with a width of 160 pixels?

Comment: You divide 160 by 6 and get about 26.667. I rounded it down to 26 so that it would fit the int type. Unfortunately, I was assigned with a width of 160 pixels so I can't change it.

Comment: (This question would be better if showing what the current code resulted in - and how that was different/incorrect.)

Comment: @user2864740, just copy the code provided and paste it in a programming software such as jGRASP. Compile it and then run it. It'll show what the code resulted in.

Comment: @ColbyLee Nope, sorry. Not my homework.

Comment: Is the fillRect alone being distorted?

Comment: No, the fillRect isn't distorted.

Comment: Then try adding one polygon at a time to see which one is screwing up your code.

Comment: You should probably try starting and ending the polygons in the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

Draw one figure at the time to see what doesn't work out the way you want it to.

Let the polygons start and end in the same spot. And don't forget to add one more point to the polygons.